# How to kill a java process started by ant exec in a platform independent way?

Tags: java, ant, jvm

I have this following  build.xml code which starts a java process on both windows and mac(depending on which os you run this build.xml) using exec, i want to kill these child processes through java(it would be great if somehow they get killed when i kill their parent process which executes this build.xml) ?

Note: antRunAsync.js is for running an exe file and antRunAsync.sh is for running a jar file.

**Build.xml>>>**

```
<target name="runscript.windows">
        <echo>This is a Windows machine.</echo>
    <exec executable="cscript.exe">
               <arg value="//NoLogo" />
               <arg value="antRunAsync.js" />  <!-- this script -->
               <arg value="${projectName}.exe" />
               <arg line="${savedTestName}"/>
            </exec>

    </target>

    <target name="runscript.mac">
        <echo>This is an Mac machine.</echo>
        <exec dir="." executable="/bin/sh">
            <arg value="./antRunAsync.sh" />
            <arg value="${projectName}.jar" />
            <arg line="${savedTestName}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
```

**antRunAsync.js >>>**

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var exeStr = "%comspec% /c";
var arg = "";
var windowStyle = 0;
var WshProcessEnv = WshShell.Environment("PROCESS");
var windowTitle = WshProcessEnv("ANTRUN_TITLE");
var outputFile = WshProcessEnv("ANTRUN_OUTPUT");
var OS = WshProcessEnv("OS");
var isWindowsNT = (OS == "Windows_NT");

// Loop through arguments quoting ones with spaces
for (var i = 0; i < WScript.Arguments.count(); i++) {
arg = WScript.Arguments(i);
if (arg.indexOf(' ') > 0)
    exeStr += " \"" + arg + "\"";
else
    exeStr += " " + arg;
}

WScript.Echo(exeStr);

var stdin = WshShell.Exec(exeStr).StdOut;
var stdout = WScript.StdOut;

while (!stdin.AtEndOfStream) {
var str = stdin.ReadLine();
stdout.WriteLine("Line " + (stdin.Line - 1) + ": " + str);
}
```

**antRunAsync.sh >>>**

```
echo $1
echo $2
java -jar $1 $2 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

JMX is one option using which you can kill java process in a platform indepedent manner. Please take look at below link.

[Is it possible to programmatically close a Java process through JMX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636473/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-close-a-java-process-through-jmx)

If you are looking for an option, where killing an ant process should cause termination of java process, i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

[ProcessHandle](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) (java9) or [jnr-posix](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix) provide general process management options. Earlier java versions can only kill direct children created through the `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec` methods.